# Remove button next to each div

Tags: jquery, loops, removechild

Here add person button add a set of text fields to add the details of the person.

And I have given Remove option to remove the respective .loop `div`, it removes the .loop `div` but when the first set is removed then Add Person button is again not adding the .loop `div` because since the .loop `div` is completely removed from the page, it is not finding that `div` to `clone`. How do I solve this?

Code here

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    clicks = 0;
            $('div.test').on('click', function () {

                $('.attnd2').show();
              $('div.loop').show();
                if ($('div.loop').length < 5) {
                    clicks++;
                    if(clicks>1){
                        newLoopDiv = $($('div.loop')[0]).clone().appendTo(".container");
                        $('input', newLoopDiv).each(function (index, element) {
                        $(element).attr('name', $(element).attr('name') + clicks);
                    });
                    }
                    else{
                    newLoopDiv = $($('div.loop')[0]).appendTo(".container");
                        $('input', newLoopDiv).each(function (index, element) {
                        $(element).attr('name', $(element).attr('name') + clicks);
                    });

                }

                }
                $( ".remove" ).click(function() {
                       $(this).closest('.loop').remove();
                    });     
            }); 


    $( ".remove" ).click(function() {
                       $(this).closest('.loop').remove();
                    });

            });
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8JQrj/6/)**

Comment: make a input fields HTML as hidden for clone and remove the HTML fields which are only visible...that way you can solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reconsider your code, just define a model div to use to clone the new rows when you click add rows.

The model div is used only for the cloning and is always hidden. The remove button remove the cloned div so the add always work.

At the end the code looks more simple too.

Code:

```
<div class='container'>
</div>
<div class="test">Add person</div>
<div class='model_container'>
    <div class="model_loop"> <strong>Person 1</strong>

        <br/>
        <input type="text" name="first name" />
        <input type="text" name="lastname" />
        <input type="text" name="mail" />
        <input type="text" name="company" />
        <div class="remove">remove</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    clicks = 0;
    $('div.test').on('click', function () {

        $('.attnd2').show();
        if ($('div.loop').length < 5) {
            clicks++;

            newLoopDiv = $($('div.model_loop')[0]).clone().appendTo(".container").removeClass("model_loop").addClass("loop").show();
            $('input', newLoopDiv).each(function (index, element) {
                $(element).attr('name', $(element).attr('name') + clicks);
            });


        }
        $(".remove").click(function () {
            $(this).closest('.loop').remove();
        });
    });


    $(".remove").click(function () {
        $(this).closest('.loop').remove();
    });

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8JQrj/10/

### EDIT

You also need to renum the name of the remaing div after a remove.

I suggest you to don't use the name attribute and parse it to remove the index, but a custom data attribute `data-progr`.

Inserted the remove action as one function using `on`.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    clicks = 0;
    $('div.test').on('click', function () {

        $('.attnd2').show();
        if ($('div.loop').length < 5) {
            clicks++;
            newLoopDiv = $($('div.model_loop')[0]).clone().appendTo(".container").removeClass("model_loop").addClass("loop").show();
            $('input', newLoopDiv).each(function (index, element) {
                $(element).attr("data-progr", clicks);
            });
        }

    });

    $("body").on('click','.remove', function () {
        $(this).closest('.loop').remove();
        clicks--;
        $('.loop').each(function (indexdiv, eldiv) {
            $('input', eldiv).each(function (index, element) {
                console.log(indexdiv)
                $(element).attr("data-progr", indexdiv);
            });
        });

    });

});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8JQrj/20/

Comment: Thanks you. Can you pls look at this fiddle, when I remove one .loop div, i want the person numbers to be renamed according to the order like person1 , person2 ...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing .loop, hide it if the $('.loop').length is 1. It might help